# Combinatorics: calcaulating options of valid password of length 5 or 6 from letters and numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I did the following excercise using the Inclusion–exclusion principle, that's how we should do that excercise, but the answer does not match my regular calcaulation, why?

The user is required to choose a password which will uphold the following requirements:

Password length is 5 or 6 characters. Characters allowed are a-z, A-Z, 0-9.

The password must contain at least one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter and at least one digit.

### How many different valid password can the user create?

First, I calcaulated total options of 5 letters and 6 letters pasword from (A-Z (26), a-z (26), 0-9 (10)).

which is $\ 62^5 + 62^6$

I made the following sets:

$\ A_1 = $ number of passwords which contains 0 lowercase letters (only uppercase and numbers).

$\ A_2 = $ number of passwords which contains 0 uppercase letters (only lowercase and numbers).

$\ A_3 = $ number of passwords which contains 0 numbers (only lowercase and uppercase).

$\ |A_1| = |A_2| = 36^5+36^6$

$\ |A_3| = 52^5+52^6$

$\ S_1 = |A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3| = 36^5+36^6+36^5+36^6+52^5+52^6=24,625,310,720$

next, I calcaulated the intersection of the sets.

$\ |A_1 \cap A_2|=10^5+10^6$

$\ |A_1 \cap A_3|= |A_2 \cap A_3|=26^5+26^6$

$\ S_2=10^5+10^6+26^5+26^6+26^5+26^6=642,694,304$

$\ S_3 = $ passwords which contains no lowercase, uppercase or numbers at all = 0

now I just calcaulated the total number of options $\ - (S_1+S_2-S_3)$

which is: $\ 57,716,368,416-25,268,005,024=32,448,363,392$

but it doesn't match this:

$\ (26*26*10*62*62) + (26*26*10*62*62*62) = 1,637,082,720$

my questions are why and which is the correct answer to this question?

Comment: Maybe you can split up the 5-character and 6-character passwords

Comment: Your "regular calculation" at the end doesn't make sense. Where did you get it from? Also, as jonnytan999 mentioned, you might as well separately calculate the totals for different number of digits.

Comment: @seth Could you just check if your method returns the the number of ways as zero in case the password length is 1 or 2. Just a sanity check since what i've calculated doesn't seem to match either of your answers, but I might have made an error somewhere.

Comment: thanks, if my second calcaulation doesn't make sense can you give me a different one so I can compare? now I see why it doesn't make sense because I choose the first place to be a lowercase, second place to be uppercase and third to be a number which has nothing to do with the question right?

Comment: It is just that you won't exhaust possibilities where the first or second characters are numbers

Comment: Your calculations are all correct except for the point where you calculated number of valid options $V$. It should be $$V=T-(S_1-S_2+S_3)$$ but what you've done is $$V=T-(S_1+S_2-S_3)$$. Fix that and you're good to go. That should return a value of 33733752000, which agrees with my work.

Comment: can someone confirm this? because I really think it should be $\ (S_1+S_2-S_3)$, any other formula to check my answer?, btw thanks bolt

Comment: Oh yeah... I didn't see that. However, that just made the answer bigger and further from the expected answer

Comment: your question asks that password must contain one lowercase letter... I think you have calculated passwords coming out from combinations with more than one lower-case letter.

Comment: and it is supposed to be $(S_1-S_2+S_3)$ because passwords which only have one type (let's say numbers) will be repeated twice in $S_1$ (No uppercase letters and lowercase letters) Therefore, we should take $S_1-S_2$

Comment: @abstract I edited the question it should be at least one lowercase letter as well

Comment: First is correct  with one minor error( Total-S1+S2-S3)and the second is wrong and the reason why it is wrong is you are imposing all the constraints at once and this reduces the number to a great magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Password length is 5 or 6 characters. Characters allowed are $a-z$, $A-Z$, $0-9$.
>
> The password must contain at least one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter and at least one digit.

Use the inclusion, exclusion principal. $|\{lud\}| - |\{lu\}|-|\{ld\}|-|\{ud\}| + |\{l\}|+|\{u\}|+|\{d\}|$

$$C= (26\!+\!26\!+\!10)^5(26\!+\!26\!+\!10\!+\!1)\!-\!(26\!+\!26)^5(26\!+\!26\!+\!1)\!- 2(26\!+\!10)^5(26\!+\!10\!+\!1)\!+\!2(26)^5(26\!+\!1)\!+\!(10)^5(10\!+\!1)$$

$$C= (62)^5(63) - (52)^5(53) - 2(36)^5(37) + 2(26)^5(27)+(10)^5(11)$$

$$C= 57,\!716,\!368,\!416 - 20,\!150,\!813,\!696 - 4,\!474,\!497,\!024 + 641,\!594,\!304+1,\!100,\!000$$

$$C= 57,\!716,\!368,\!416 -24,\!625,\!310,\!720 + 642,\!694,\!304$$

$$C= 33,\!733,\!752,\!000$$

---

> but it doesn't match this:
>
> $(26∗26∗10∗62∗62)+(26∗26∗10∗62∗62∗62)=1,637,082,720$

That only counts passwords *starting with* one upper case, one lower case, and one digit, --in that order-- *followed by* 2 or 3 more symbols from any group.

It does not count, for instance, "$\mathrm{HeLL0}$"