# Combinatorics: help with the Inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

$B=\{5,6,7,8,9\}$

$K$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ ($K\subseteq AXB)$

1. in how many $K$'s - $1 \notin domain(K)$ ?
2. in how many $K$'s - $\{1,2,3\}\subseteq domain(K)$ (use the
   Inclusion-exclusion principle).

for example, one option is  $K =\{(2,5),(2,6),(3,5),(4,9)\}$

$domain(K)=\{2,3,4\}$

---

1. I'm pretty sure it's all the subsets of the set

   $\{(2,5),(2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(2,9),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8),(4,9)\}
       = 2^{15}=32,768 $

   which is weird because all the subsets of $AXB$ is
   $2^{20}=1,048,576$ and only $32,768$ of them don't include (1,x)
   elements?
2. I need help determining what sets I use for the Inclusion-disclusion
   principle, is it:

   $A_1=$ the set of $\{1,2\} \subseteq domain(K) $

   $A_2=$ the set of $\{1,3\} \subseteq domain(K) $

   $A_3=$ the set of $\{1,4\} \subseteq domain(K) $

   $A_4=$ the set of $\{2,3\} \subseteq domain(K) $

   $A_5=$ the set of $\{2,4\} \subseteq domain(K) $

   $A_6=$ the set of $\{3,4\} \subseteq domain(K) $

Comment: I think I got it wrong for 2, should be $A_1 = $ the set of 1 is not in domain K.  $A_2 = $ the set of 2 is not in domain K. and  $A_3 = $ the set of 3 is not in domain K. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks correct.  It's the possible relations from $\{2,3,4\}$ to $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$, of which there are $2^{3 \times 5}$.
2. I think we're meant to use the idea of part 1. here.

   - Include: There are $2^{4 \times 5}$ relations.
   - Exclude: There are $2^{3 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $1$ in the domain.  There are $2^{3 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $2$ in the domain.  There are $2^{3 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $3$ in the domain.
   - Include: There are $2^{2 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $1$ and $2$ in the domain.  There are $2^{2 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $1$ and $3$ in the domain.  There are $2^{2 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $2$ and $3$ in the domain.
   - Exclude: There are $2^{1 \times 5}$ relations that don't contain $1$, $2$ and $3$ in the domain.

Comment: I think you are right Rebecca, are you sure it's not (total number of K's) - ($S_1 - S_2+S_3$)? or is it the same thing as your answer?, it's just what I've been told in this thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805059/combinatorics-calcaulating-options-of-valid-password-of-length-5-or-6-from-lett/805102#805102, and I want to understand it ;)

Comment: ok I checked it, it's the same thing ;)